# iPhone 6 Slide Out Menu

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to make a collapsible slide out menu bar from scratch.  I decided to try a UISplitViewController().  When I use an iPad simulator, I get a collapsible menu on the right side like desired.  However, when I try it on my iPhone 6, the master view and detail view are shown on totally different screens instead of partially overlapping each other until a decision is made.  Is it possible to get a split screen overlap when viewed on both the smaller devices (iPhone 5/6) and bigger devices?

The posted `UISplitViewController` is below:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let splitVC = UISplitViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = splitVC

    print(splitVC.collapsed)
    var nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MasterViewControllerTableViewController())
    var nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    splitVC.viewControllers = [nav1, nav2]
    splitVC.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryOverlay // this does not help?
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: You will have to use a third-party library or write your own objects. No UIKit objects will do what you desire.

Comment: Indeed. The split view controller acts like 2 separate view controllers on iPhones (by design.) The one thing you CAN'T do is use a split view controller as the basis for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have built one from scratch but I would advise just using one of the pre-existing libraries. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ is a good place to check. In the filter above select Sort: rating, Platform: iOS. You can even run the code online to test it. Most of the code for this controls is hosted on github.

If you do decide to build one there are plenty of tutorials if you google for “swift build slide out menu”. The code you have does a small subset of what you’ll need so there’s no simple “add this” or “change that” to get it to work.